# MontyHall java code. Help for java beginner

Tags: java

im fairly new to java and as my first assignment i need to simulate a MontyHall game using two classes. Door and MontyHall.

My main issue is with the class MontyHall. im having trouble simulating the selection of a random door and proceeding after that. Any help or hints to put me in the right direction would be much help.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class MontyHall {



  // ADD YOUR INSTANCE VARIABLES HERE

   private int door1; //door that holds the prize
   private int door2; //one of the remaining two doors that doesnt have a prize
   private int door3; //the last remaining door that doesnt have a prize
   private int door4; //a door that the user chooses



   Random generator = new Random();

  /** 
      * Initializes the three doors.
      */
   public MontyHall(){
 // REPLACE THE BODY OF THIS METHOD WITH YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION

     Door door1 = new Door("prizeDoor");
     Door door2 = new Door("hostDoor");
     Door door3 = new Door("finalDoor");
     Door door4 = new Door("selectedDoor");



   }

  /** 
      * Simulates one Monty Hall game.  
      * <ol>
      * <li>Resets all three doors</li>
   * <li>Simulates the selection of one of the doors by the player</li>
   * <li>Simulates opening of an empty door by the host</li>
   * <li>prints the outcome for switching and not switching door to standard output</li>
   * </ol>
      */
   public void oneGame(){
 // REPLACE THE BODY OF THIS METHOD WITH YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION

    int door1 = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assign a value for door1

    System.out.println("The prize was behind door " + door1);

    while(door2 == door1){
      int door2 = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assign a value for door2
    }


    while(door3 == door1 || door3 == door2){
      int door3 = generator.nextInt(3)+1; //assign a value for door3
    }


   if (((door4 == door1) && (Door.SelectedByPlayer() == true)) || ((door4 == door2) && (Door.SelectedByPlayer() == true))){
    System.out.println("Switching strategy would have lost");
   } else{
    System.out.println("Switching strategy would have won"); 
   }
   }


  /** 
      * Simulates a random selection of one of the three doors.
      * @return the door randomly selected  
      */
   private int pickADoor(){
 // REPLACE THE BODY OF THIS METHOD WITH YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION



     int door4 = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
     return this.door4;


     System.out.println("The player selected door " + door4);
   }  





 /** 
      * Simulates the opening of one of the other doors once the player selected one.
      * It should  open a door chosen randomly among the ones that don't have the prize and
      * that are not selected by the player
      * 
      *   @param prizeDoor the door that hides the prize
      *   @param selectedDoor the door that was selected by the player
      *   @return the door opened
      */
   private int openOtherDoor(int prizeDoor, int selectedDoor){

 // REPLACE THE BODY OF THIS METHOD WITH YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION

     prizeDoor = door1;
     selectedDoor = door4;

     if(selectedDoor == prizeDoor){
       int hostDoor = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
     }
     while(door2 != selectedDoor && door2 != prizeDoor){
       int door2 = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
     }
     return this.door2;

   System.out.println("The host opened door " + door2);

   }
```

Comment: One word - [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  You seem to have some basic conceptual problems in your code, both about Java and about programming in general, which are somewhat beyond StackOverflow's intended scope.  SO is not a place for discussions, or where you can get tutorials or cover basic information that is available elsewhere.  For your situation, I think talking to the professor or teaching assistant is the right direction.

Comment: @samer-alsaadi: did you learnt about arrays already?
Also... Considering what kind of state a door has, and what operations a door has.

Comment: As an example: Some doors have goats behind them - maybe you could represent that as a boolean?

Also, doors can be .open()ed. hmmm... so maybe they need to track if they have been opened already.

Also, MountyHall selects(aDoor), maybe? :)

Comment: @luizTavares your putting me in the right direction. thank you. In order to track if doors have been opened, would if statement be useful?

Comment: @samer-alsaadi: Could be done that way.

Comment: What I would do is... declare a boolean called "open" on door. declare a open() method, that will toggle that boolean on.

Comment: so now doors know how to open themselves. :) then maybe you need a isOpen() on door, so montyHall can query each door to see if it's opened already :)

Comment: OOP is a bit of a strange thing.... Door opening themselves, who would know that? :)

Comment: @LuizTavares thanks again! these info will help me alot much appreciated

Comment: Don't give up, programming, logic, and oop is quite hard for most people at start. It will get better with time, practice will make it way easier.

Comment: I completely agree. And it is actually quite alot of fun to be challenged this way

Comment: Lemme see if I can help a bit more. Everybody mentioned arrays - they're quite useful data structure when handling more than one thing of the same type. If your teacher taught you about them, he/she probably expect you to use it here ;).

Comment: Also, there's four doors in your code, and as far as I know, monty hall only uses three doors: `Door door1 = new Door("prizeDoor");
Door door2 = new Door("hostDoor");
Door door3 = new Door("finalDoor");
Door door4 = new Door("selectedDoor");`. So... Door1 to Door3 are actual, honest doors. But there isn't really a fourth door, right? The guest selects between door1, door2 and door3. So... door4 shouldn't probably be a new instance. maybe `Door selectedDoor` should just point (or refer) to one of the other instances?!

Comment: Yeah its probably a good idea to use arrays. So lets say i declare the 3 doors as String[] doors={"door1","door2","door3"), i then would want to use random generator and then assign each door a value. im guessing using praseInt would help?

Comment: Doors aren't Strings! They're Doors! How about Door[] doors = new Door[];

Comment: Then maybe create them? Keeping it simple: Door[0] = new Door()... and so on

Comment: Ohhh gotcha! will fix it now

Comment: hmm... if you're using the array, why not use the array index to select a door? maybe if you can generate a random number between 0 and 2 (three doors, so they're numbered 0, 1,2, right?) we could use that to select a door :)

Comment: So we got so far... We need An array, a RNG to select one of the doors....

Comment: After that, we'll probably need to remember which door has the prize.

Comment: MountyHall can know this, but maybe the Door itself can know? hmmmm Tough call ;)

Comment: How to model that? Well... it depends. The best way of model this is to ask yourself: do every instance of Door that I'll ever create is interested in knowing if they have a goat behind it?

Comment: And now philosophy starts. If you're modeling Doors that will be use for more than MountyHall then NO, not all Doors are interested and this state belong somewhere else.

Comment: on the other hand, if all your Doors are only ever be used to play Monty Hall, then Why not? If the goat is behind them, they seem to be the most interested part :)

Comment: haha this is getting interesting. Okay im revising my code. What ill do now is: Create Door array that holds three doors. then use random generator to get a number and then assign that number to one of the doors in the array. and i would probably do the same for the other two doors.

Answer (score -2):

The main cause of this difficulty is the **random** function you're using in your program. In fact, it is not efficient and it is a classical issue in java(and other programming languages). to know more about this topic check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725145/java-efficient-way-to-generate-lots-of-random-numbers).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523492/choosing-random-numbers-efficiently) can be a good directive for your issue.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Your wording is misleading. This mistake is in the OP's code, this has absolutely nothing to do with "_java(and other programming languages)_"; it has to do with basic logic.